# cakephp routing: display specific search results

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I've taken over a project from another developer and am fairly new to cakephp. Hopefully, I'm framing my question and approach in an appropriate manner.

I have a page that I want to display specific search results and I wish to name it with a specific URL. This URL returns the correct results:

http://www.advancelegaljobs.com/jobs/search/radius:Massachusetts-Boston

This is the URL I wish to use:

http://www.advancelegaljobs.com/boston-legal-jobs

I've attempted numerous variations in routes.php, but none seem to work. For example:

```
Router::connect('/boston-legal-jobs', array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'search', 'radius:Massachusetts-Boston'));
```

or

```
Router::connect('/boston-legal-jobs', array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'search'), array('passedArgs'=>array('radius','Massachusetts-Boston')));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATED:

I think I'm getting close on this. Changing the route to:

```
Router::connect('/boston-legal-jobs', array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'search', array('radius' => 'Massachusetts-Boston')));
```

produces this when I log passedArgs:

(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [radius] => Massachusetts-Boston
        )

)

When I use the URL that produces correct results this is what is logged:

(
    [radius] => Massachusetts-Boston
)

So I'm guessing my code is nesting my array in an unnamed array? Any thoughts on correcting this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps try adding this:

`Router::connectNamed(array('radius'));`

> When making custom routes, a common pitfall is that using named parameters will break your custom routes. In order to solve this you should inform the Router about which parameters are intended to be named parameters.

See [Named Parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/view/947/Named-parameters).

Comment: Thanks Ross. This makes sense, but unfortunately it still returns all search results. The search action cycles through a set of parameters, region, specialty, industry, etc., so one thought is just to make a new action that just expects region, but that seems like a terribly long-handed approach.

Comment: I must confess I've tried pretty much the same before and given up ! A bit of googling uncovers similar situations, but no definitive solution unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best or correct way to solve this, but here is what worked, after a lot of trial and error. The route:

```
Router::connect('/boston-legal-jobs', array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'search', array('radius' => 'Massachusetts-Boston')));
```

My action was expecting **$this->passedArgs['radius']** but in this routing, 'radius' is the first key in an array.

Simply adding another condition for **$this->passedArgs[0]['radius']** did the trick.